# How to send customize email from sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: exm

Previously in Exm 3.5 we send customize email using **AsyncSendingManager** code.

```
AsyncSendingManager(messageItem).SendStandardMessage(recipientId)
```

In Exm 9.0.1, there is no implementation this class. Is there any option available for sending customize email from exm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sitecore 9.0.1, the way that Sitecore servers send messages through EXM has changed a bit due to the introduction of Rebus Messaging Service.

To send emails now, you'll want to instantiate the client api service.

```
IClientApiService _clientApiService;

public ClassConstructor(IClientApiService clientApiService)
{
  _clientApiService = clientApiService;

  var messageInfo = new AutomatedMessage();
  messageInfo.MessageId = messageId; //Guid of Message
  messageInfo.ContactIdentifier = contactIdentifier; //Contact Identifier
  messageInfo.CustomTokens = dictionaryOfTokens //Custom Tokens
  messageInfo.TargetLanguage = language //Language

  _clientApiService.SendAutomatedMessage(messageInfo);
}
```

This will send the custom message through EXM as usual.

For reference, there are other methods that the Client API uses as well:

```
namespace Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.Services
{
  public interface IClientApiService
  {
    void SendAutomatedMessage(AutomatedMessage automatedMessage);

    void Subscribe(SubscribeMessage subscribeMessage);

    void Unsubscribe(UnsubscribeMessage unsubscribeMessage);

    void ConfirmSubscription(ConfirmSubscriptionMessage confirmSubscriptionMessage);

    void RegisterEmailOpen(EmailOpenMessage emailOpenMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using the code above to trigger the delivery of messages successfully, but we have some arbitrary custom tokens in the message that we're trying to fill using the `CustomTokens` dictionary and they never get filled.  Is it sufficient for the Dictionary `key` to match the token in the email, as `$key$` or do the custom tokens _have_ to be xDB facets?